# How to override Spring Security default configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a little problem with Spring Boot. I really like Spring Boot, it's very convenient tool, which allow me to focus on logic implementation instead of beans configuration. BUT... I want to override default Spring Security configuraton. I've created SecurityConfig class, and Spring Boot loads that class when starts. I can see my config beans on address/beans.

But configuration is still default (I guess).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
    
    protected void cofigure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/app/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/error");
    }
}
```

I've declared user with username: user, and pass: password. I've also declared, that Spring Security must allow any user to see the index site: localhost:port/app/ .

I supposed that If I enter localhost:port/app/ url into browser, Spring Security let me in. Instead, I get localhost:port/login page and default Spring Security login form. Moreover, username and password declared in AuthenticationManager doesnt't work.

But if I type my app properties credentias it works.

```
security.user.name=testUser
security.user.password=testPass
security.user.role=USER
```

Conclusion: It seems that Spring Boot loads my custom Spring Securty config, but it doesn't use it.

Why?

EDIT:

Now my SecurityConf looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("ROLE_USER");
    }
    
    protected void cofigure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
         http
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/app/").permitAll()
         .and().formLogin();
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>szczepanski.gerard</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-edu-fm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootEduFreemarker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And stack trace occuring when Spring Boot is initializing:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.con
fig.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.
security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springfr
amework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframe
work.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired 
dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot start with ROLE_ (it is au
tomatically added)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(Autowire
dAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-bea
ns-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.jav
a:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans
-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4
.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java
:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractA
utowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapa
bleBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-bea
ns-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.jav
a:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans
-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4
.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[sprin
g-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.4
.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2
.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2
.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.
0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30
.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30
]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.
30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30
]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30
]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springfra
mework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.s
pringframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of aut
owired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot start with ROLE_ (i
t is automatically added)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(Auto
wiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.
4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(Autowire
dAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection o
f autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot start with ROL
E_ (it is automatically added)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:1
64) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:
1413) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.
java:1029) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.ja
va:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(Auto
wiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration
': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot 
start with ROLE_ (it is automatically added)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(Autowire
dAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-bea
ns-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.jav
a:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans
-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4
.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:
534) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:
523) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWeb
SecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:53) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0
.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113) ~[sp
ring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129) ~[spring-expressi
on-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49) ~[spring-expression-4.2.
4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347) ~[spring-e
xpression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-exp
ression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEA
SE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242) ~[spring-expression-4.
2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:1
61) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot start with ROLE_ (it is automatically added)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$
UserDetailsBuilder.roles(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:167) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE
]
    at edu.spring.boot.app.security.SecurityConfiguration.configureGlobal(SecurityConfiguration.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(Auto
wiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:654) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.
4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(Autowire
dAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What if you remove the security properties security.user.* ?

Comment: Spring Boot will create default user with username: username, and generated password, and will show me this generated password in log when initializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for security configure settings (not AuthenticationManager).

First of all, according to Spring Boot dot, we have to add @EnableWebSecurity annotation.

Second of all, we have to override configure method WITH @Override annotation AND super.configure(http) at the end of the method.

So the working configuration code looks like this:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity //Very important!
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Profile("dev")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override //Very important!
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/app/user/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/app/posts/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/app/*").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/app/")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/", true)
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/app/forbidden");
        super.configure(http); //Very important!
    }
}
```

Now my configurations is loading, and works properly.

Comment: Please how can I call this from the front using angular? I mean that how can I send the request with the username and the password from the front to the back?

Comment: This worked! EnableWebSecurity and EnableGlobalMethodSecurity along with a custom SpringSecurityConfig-class allowed me to have basic authentication on spring-boot actuator sensitive endpoints (e.g. shutdown). Thanks! (btw.: I used configureGlobal-method)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that Spring Boot loads my custom Spring Securty config, but
>   it doesn't use it.

You did not configure your `AuthenticationManager` correctly. You should use `@Autowired`:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

You can read more on spring security documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration). Also, make sure that your configuration is going to be picked up by spring boot. You can read more about standard project structure in spring boot [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code) and its security integration [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security).

**Update** Based on the stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot start
>   with ROLE_

You should drop the `ROLE_` prefix in `roles("ROLE_USER")`, Just use `roles("USER")`.

Comment: It throws me an org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException excepton when Spring Boot is initiaizing.

Comment: Update your question with whole stacktrace and add your project structure and `pom.xml`.

Comment: Ok, done. I want to mention that I dont need to secure any URL. Only some methods in my services.

Comment: Please how can I call this from the front using angular? I mean that how can I send the request with the username and the password from the front to the back?

Answer (score 0):

did you remove this code?

```
 @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```