# How to override default Spring Boot Login page?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm totally new with Spring Boot 2 and I have this simple application that I'm trying to run. Unfortunately, each time I run my service, I end up with this login form from Spring Boot. Is there any way I can override this?

I've already tried the solution from this question but it didn't work for me:

[How to override Spring Security default configuration in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600488/how-to-override-spring-security-default-configuration-in-spring-boot)

Here is what I have so far for the code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.EnableHystrixDashboard;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

/**
 * Defines the application, supports service registry, circuit breaker 
 * for Spring Boot application.
 * 
 * @EnableJpaRepositories - add this to enable 
 * 
 * @author himanshu sharma
 * @since June 2017
 */
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:service-config.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.manulife.ap.*, io.swagger")
public class Application{
    @Autowired
    DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    /**
     * Application start point.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello () {
        return "Hello from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

--**EDIT:@devshawn**--
I tried the solution of excluding the `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` but I somehow got this error message when I tried to access my endpoint:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Spring Boot 2, as you did not mention which version of Spring you are using. In spring boot 2, you cannot disable the default login via properties files as you could in spring boot 1. There's a few ways of doing this depending on what you're trying to achieve.

## Permit All Access, Secure Endpoints Later

Add a class titled `SecurityConfig` that looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

This removes authentication on all endpoints in your service. Later on, you can configure security further via this class.

## Remove Security Auto Configuration

When Spring Security is found on the classpath, Spring Boot automatically configures security. You can remove it all together if you don't want it auto configured by changing your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution and I tried both of them. However, the first one still redirected me to `localhost:8080/login` when I tried `localhost:8080/greeting`. As for the second one, I'll edit my post and paste an image. For the version, I tried running `spring --version` on the command line and got `Spring CLI v2.1.3.RELEASE`. Is this the proper version you were asking about?

Comment: @Uzi - That is the version, yep! So, `RequestMapping`s only work on classes annotated with `@RestController`. Add that to your file and it should start working. The first one not working was likely due to component scan not catching your newly created configuration file.

Comment: Holy crap that worked the instant I add @RestController. Thanks for the help. I'll add the version in my question just in case someone might use this in the future. Thanks again. May you live a long happy life